# copy / update the child index using parent index field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, migration, elasticsearch-2.4

I have an index with parent-child relation in elastic 2.4.

This index has 2 type, one is a parent and second is the child. Both have different mappings except a common field that is `field1`.

Index mappings look like below:

type `parent`:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "field1": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "field2": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

type `child`:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "field3": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "field1": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have updated the child index mapping and add another field same as the parent index that is field2.

Now the mapping of child looks like this:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "field3": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "field1": {
      "type": "long"
    }
    "field2": {
      "type": "long"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to copy the value from parent to child on the basis of a common field that is `field1`.
document in the child index should get updated with `field2` which have the common `field1`.

I tried the `_reindex` api and update_by_query but did not find any good and fast solution to do the same. As I tried `_reindex` api with source and destination as below, but there is the limitation that it will create new document instead of updating the document by the common fiels that is `field1`.

I tried the below solution.

```
index_name/_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "index_name",
    "type": "parent"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "index_name",
    "type": "child"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._dest.field2 = ctx._source.field2"
  }
}
```

This gives me an error that we can not use the same index as source and destination. How can I fix the same? or is there a better approach to do the same.

Comment: Could you just put all this in a new index then ditch the old one?

Comment: I got your poing but problem is this I have to add one more filed along with the old fields in child index. @doctorlove

Comment: I don't think I can help properly, but had a similar thing to do, and when I hand-crafted an id for each record I added, it helped in the upsert because I could find what I wanted and add new fields.